# Mail from Linux server goes to spam

Tags: linux, email

I've made .sh file which send me the mail if disk usage is above a certain level. The script is working fine but the mail goes to spam instead of inbox! What should I do? Do I need to configure anything on the server? I'm new to Linux server.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

current_usage=$( df -h | grep '/var' | awk '{percent+=$4;} END{print percent}' | column -t )
max_usage=50

if [ $current_usage -ge $max_usage ]; then
    mailbody="Max usage exceeded. Your disk usage is at ${current_usage}."
    echo "Sending mail..."

echo ${mailbody} | mail -s "Disk alert!" "mymail@gmail.com"


elif [ ${current_usage%?} -lt ${max_usage%?} ]; then
    echo "No problems. Disk usage at ${current_usage}." > /dev/null
fi
```

Mail looks like:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about gmail's spam filtering rules, and has nothing to do with unix or linux.  BTW, the most likely cause is that the mail is coming from a bogus domain (localhost.localdomain).  Maybe try changing the sender address so that it's from your gmail address. or some other valid address that belongs to you.

Comment: @cas No, it's about configuring the mailer correctly to set sender, possibly signing it etc.!  Almost any e-mail service will mark an e-mail as spam that has "root@localhost.localdomain" as a sender!

Comment: @Ned64 It ends up being both situations most of the time, to be fair it is a gray area.

Comment: @Ned64 I disagree.  Spam filtering rules used by a mail service provider, even those used by "almost any email service", are about the mail service provider, not about unix or linux.   We have **no way of knowing** for sure what the rules used by any SP are, or which ones are triggered by the SP.  It may be the "Alert!" in the subject.  It may be the bogus email address.  It may be both together scoring highly enough to be flagged as spam.  gmail's spam filtering rules are a secret known only to gmail - **the best we can do is guess**.

Comment: Jay, also take a look at https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en and in particular the third column option. But sending email from `root@localhost.localdomain` is not a good starting place.

Comment: @cas The sender is regulated in RFC822, RFC1123 and others. Not recipient server dependent. Let's also see whether we can help the OP, which is the reason for SE's existence.

Comment: @roaima I believe the link is about using gmail's mail servers, whereas Jay is using his own.

Comment: @Ned64 RFCs do not define gmail's spam policy.  spam filtering policy is absolutely server dependent (free hint: don't try newbiesplaining the basics of email to someone who's been running unix mail servers with a particular emphasis on spam filtering, probably for decades before you even heard of unix. or email).   BTW, I helped the OP even though their question is off-topic here - by providing pretty much the same info as in your answer, **before** you answered.

Comment: @Ned64 I believe the OP is using their own, yes, but if they are trying to route to Gmail from an invalid sender domain they will have no chance of delivery unless they follow Gmail's recommendations (rules). I don't accept Internet email from `root@localhost.localdomain`, either.

Answer (score 1):

The From: sender is not set correctly.  If you send an e-mail that is not supposed to look like Spam, set the sender to something like root@yourdomain.com (try `mail -r root@mydomain.com`):

```
echo ${mailbody} | mail -s "Disk alert!" -r root@mydomain.com mymail@gmail.com
```

The sender domain (FQDN, "fully qualified domain name") is determined by the mail backend software by entries in `/etc/hosts` and/or `/etc/hostname` and can also be set in its configuration file(s). Since these are not set correctly we force `mail` to override it here. A better solution would therefore be to configure `sendmail` or whatever is used here. (Check `dmesg` output or `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/maillog` (dependent on system here) for error messages by the mailer not finding its FQDN).

If you wish to go further please read up on DKIM (e-mail signing) and SPF (sender protection framework).  Adhering to one or both of these two can help, even if it is no guarantee for success.

The latter (SPF) is easier: Make an entry in your DNS entries (for the server/sender domain in question) that looks like this:

```
yourdomain.com   TXT   "v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 +a +mx ~all"
```

where you need to replace `1.2.3.4` with your IP address.  It basically says that mail from `whatever@yourdomain.com` can only come from the IP address listed here. This also gives credibility to mail coming from this IP address claiming to be from `yourdomain.com`.

Comment: So it should be like `echo ${mailbody} | mail -s "Disk alert!" "mymail@gmail.com" -r root@mydomail.com`?

Comment: Yes, but I would place the `-r ...` option before the To: address.

Comment: Did it work? It should probably be noted that the domain you are going to use is the one associated (via DNS) with this server (or one of them)!

Comment: If you are using postfix, in your main,cf file, make sure that myhostname is set to the fully qualified domain name of the server = server1.somedomain.co.uk.

Comment: ... That's in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

Comment: `mail -r root@mydomain.com` not working

Comment: @JayPatel Please elaborate "not working": Does the command not accept the "-r", or does gmail flag it as spam, or what?

Comment: The command is working! I get the mail in which "from" is marked as my domain name but it goes to spam

Comment: So what is your hostname set to in your main.cf file?

Comment: @JayPatel Maybe this is the best you can do without more complicated things like using SPF, DKIM and the like. Please have a look at the Header in GMail -> Arrow Button at top right of mail sub window -> Show Original. The headers will tell you some of what GMail did not like.  Post it here to let us help you (obfuscate your IP address and domain if you like),

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. Because **localhost.localdomain** is non-existent domain(doesn't have any DNS records in the internet), gmail can't resolve it. You can fix it by clicking "Not spam", or if you configure your mail server with public IP and DNS records.